Linear Algebra Done Right 7F Exercise 27 on closest unitary operator to a given operator
Suppose V is a nonzero finite dimensional inner product space over F, where F is either R or C.
Given T, an operator on V, and $s_{1},...,s_{n}$ are the singular values of T. Let $e_{1},...,e_{n}$ and $f_{1},...,f_{n}$ be orthonormal bases of V such that $$Tv = s_{1}\langle v, e_{1}\rangle f_{1}+...+s_{n}\langle v, e_{n}\rangle f_{n}$$ for all $v\in V$. Define another operator S on V with $$Sv = \langle v, e_{1}\rangle f_{1}+...+\langle v, e_{n}\rangle f_{n}$$
From the above I know that S is unitary and $||T-S|| = max\{|s_{1}-1|,...,|s_{n}-1|\}$.
I want to show that given any unitary operator E on V, $||T-E|| \geq ||T-S||$.
I tried using a few equality formula, like writing $$||T-E|| \geq |(||T||-||E||)| = |max(s_{1},...,s_{n})-1| = |max(s_{1}-1,...,s_{n}-1)|$$ but apparently this is too low a bound for the desired conclusion (really thought I had it there). Writing $$||T-S|| \leq ||T|| + ||S|| = max(s_{1},...,s_{n}) + 1$$ doesn't seem helpful either. What angle have I missed?

This question links to a paper with a proof, although it is phrased in terms of matrices.

Thanks for the link.
I am not very familiar with matrix norm, but I can understand, interpreting matrix norm as the norm of corresponding operator (given a basis and inner product on the vector space), that the linked question is identical to mine, and the mentioned statement the OP find immediately clear corresponds to $||T−S||=max{|s_{1}−1|,...,|s_{n}−1|}$ here.

But I have trouble understanding the paper. It says that A = UH, where U is unitary and H is hermitian positive semi-definite, which if I am understanding correctly, corresonds to T = QP, where T is any operator and Q is a unitary operator and P is a positive operator (Polar decomposition). How does A-U correspond to T-S in the exercise? Isn't M(S) equal to the SVD of M(T) but swapping the diagonal matrix with the identity matrix?

Frankly I am also having a hard time translating my knowledge to make sense of the derivation below the stated theorem.

A one-line proof similar to what the OP has tried: for any unit vector $e$, $$\|T-E\|\ge \|(T-E)e\|=\|Te-Ee\|\ge \big\lvert \|Te\|-\|Ee\|\big\rvert=\big\lvert \|Te\|-1 \big\rvert$$

Old answer:
I have not read the linked solution, but this is very simple calculation.
Assume $|s_1-1|=\max_j |s_j-1|$, we only need to show $$\|(T-E)e_1\|\ge |s_1-1|$$
We have $Te_1=s_1f_1$ and let $Ee_1=\sum_{i}c_if_i$ where $\sum |c_i|^2 = 1$. Now $$\|(T-E)e_1\|^2=|s_1-c_1|^2 + \sum_{i=2}^n |c_i|^2 = (s_1-c_1)(s_1-\overline{c_1}) + \sum_{i\ge 2} |c_i|^2 = s_1^2-2\text{Re}(c_1)s_1+1$$
And $|\text{Re}(c_1)|\le |c_1|\le 1$, we have $$s_1^2-2\text{Re}(c_1)s_1+1\ge s_1^2+1 - |2\text{Re}(c_1)s_1|\ge s_1^2+1-2s_1=(s_1-1)^2$$
Remark:
Here is an intuitive explanation for the above calculation. $Te_i$ is just a vector of norm $s_i$, and when $E$ varies, $Ee_i$ is just an arbitrary unit vector. Therefore geometrically, the distance between $Te_i$ and $Ee_i$ (on the unit sphere) is at least $|s_i-1|$.

Thanks. Interesting, so $||(T-E)e_{j}||$ would happen to be larger than $||s_{j}-1||$, where j is the index such that $||s_{j}-1||$ is maximum. I wouldn't have thought this to be true, or rather, be motivated to do so. I wonder if there is some other explanation to this than the explicit calculation.

Oh actually, $||(T-E)e_{j}||$ is larger or equal than $||s_{j}-1||$ for j = 1,...,n by your derivation.

@Tim, the motivation to try this is apparently, only one singular value $s_j$ matters for the bound, so maybe only the basis vector $e_j$ for that singular value matters. This turned out to be true systematically.

@Tim, after you motivated me to think more conceptually, I found a geometric interpretation and then a simple proof. The key is to use vector norm instead of operator norm used in your attempt.

I see. So using the operator norm fails to be useful because we are forced to have ||T|| = max(s1,...,sn), but with vector norm we can make ||Te|| equal to one of s1,...,sn and so be able to make |||Te||-1| maximum, equal to ||T-S||, which then implies ||T-E||>=||T-S||.

Learned something here. Thanks again.
